# Mathastext, have math font be italic or bold according to text

Tags: mathastext

I recently tried `\usepackage{mathastext}` and I really like the effect, which is that the math is in the same font as the text, instead of popping-out of it. However, this effect is lost as soon as the text is in italic (or in bold). Is there a way to have, at least for italic, a math font that adapts automatically?

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathastext}

\begin{document}

The math, like $f(x)=2^x$, is like the text. This is a cool feature
as long as you do not have an $a$ as a math symbol.

\textit{But if you switch to italic, the math like $f(x)=2^x$ pops-out again.}

\textbf{And this is worse in bold as $f(x)=2^x$ shows.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I read long time ago they work better than \textit and \textbf and should be favored, but cannot remember what was the argument. Maybe related to spacing.

Comment: @Arnaud - The claim that "[`\it` and `\bf`] work better than `\textit` and `\textbf` and should be favored" is wholly unsupported by facts. For sure, `\bf` and `\it` cannot be combined to generate ***bold-italic text***. In contrast, `\textbf` and `\textit` *can* be combined without fuss or muss.

Comment: OK fixed the \it vs \textit thing. Thanks for updating my knowledge about this.

Comment: You want to declare math versions and switch between them with, e.g. `\MTversion[normal]` and `\MTversion[bold]`.  See section 1.4 of the `mathastext` manual.

Comment: The `\text` command from `amsmath` follows the current style of the surrounding text.

Comment: @Davislor, thanks, but \text for putting text in the middle of a math formula, which is not what I'm trying to do